# Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be two sequences of real numbers such that series $a_n^2$ and $b_n^2$ converge. Then the series $a_nb_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be two sequences of real numbers such that series $\sum a_n^2$ and $\sum b_n^2$ converge. Then the series $\sum a_nb_n$

A. is absolutely convergent

B. may not converge

C.is always convergent, but maynot converge absolutely

D.converges to 0

**Attempt**

I took $a_n =(-1)^n$ and $b_n=1$. Then , $a_nb_n$ is not convergent.So this removes options C and D.If i take $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and $b_n=1$, it removes option A. So B is left. But i am not sure

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is talking about convergence of series $\sum a_n^2$ and others, not sequences $a_n^2$ themselves.

Comment: Your examples are invalid: in both cases, $\sum b_n^2$ fails to converge.

Comment: why does $\sum_k 1$ converge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
 |ab| = |a| |b| \leq 2 |a| |b| \leq |a|^2 + |b|^2 = a^2 + b^2.
$$
Because $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n^2 < \infty$ und $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n^2 < \infty$ it follows that
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n b_n|
 \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_n^2 + b_n^2)
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n^2 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n^2
 < \infty,
$$
so the series converges absolutely.

PS: This shows that A. holds, and thus also answers if B. and C. hold. Notice that D. does not hold; take for example $a_0 = b_0 = 1$ and $a_n = b_n = 0$ for $n > 0$.

Comment: Note that you reordered the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_n^2 + b_n^2)$ to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n^2 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n^2$ which is only possible because the latter two series converge absolutely (because of the square) by assumption.

Comment: Not really: Because all summands are non-negative we can rearrange however we want without having to worry. This works even if the sums do not converge (then both sides are $\infty$). (This is basicly a special case of Tonelli’s theorem.)

Comment: I only know Tonelli as making it possible to say that $\sum_m\sum_n a_{mn} = \sum_n\sum_m a_{mn}$.
By Cauchy's convergence test we know that for convergent series $\sum_n x_n, \sum_n y_n$ we have
$$\left|\sum_{n=N}^M (x_n+y_n)\right| \leq \left|\sum_{n=N}^M x_n \right| +\left|\sum_{n=N}^My_n\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$
and thus $\sum_n (x_n+y_n)$ converges.
But you're right, that this does hold for divergent series with non-negative summands as well since
$\sum_n x_n \leq \sum_n (x_n+y_n)$ and thereby also the right hand side diverges.

Comment: More generally Tonelli states that for $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B},\nu)$ and a ($\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}$)-measurable function $f \colon X \times Y \to [0,\infty]$ we have $\int_{X \times Y} f(x,y) \,\text{d}(\mu\times\nu)(x,y)=\int_X\int_Y f(x,y) \,\text{d}\nu(y) \,\text{d}\mu(x)=\int_Y\int_X f(x,y) \,\text{d}\mu(x) \,\text{d}\nu(y)$. For the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$ we get $\sum_{n,m \in \mathbb{N}} a_{mn}=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sum_{m \in \mathbb{N}} a_{mn}=\sum_{m \in \mathbb{N}}\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_{mn}$ if $a_{nm} \geq 0$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I recall as well. But I still don't understand how that can be applied to see that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (x_n+y_n) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} x_n + \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} y_n$ for non-negative $x_n,y_n$. What choice of $a_{mn}$ yields this?

Sorry for taking so long to get it - it might just be the aftermath of the New Year's Eve celebrations.

Comment: How does less than product less than infinity justifies convergence

Comment: @SvenPistre: After thinking about it for some time I figured that calling it a special case of Tonelli isn’t really such a great idea. Seems like I wasn’t as unaffected by sleepiness as I thought. This being said we can still use Tonelli to show the statement: Consider $c_{mn}$ defined as $c_{0n} = a_n^2$, $c_{1n} = b_n^2$ and $c_{mn} = 0$ for $m \geq 2$. Then $\sum_n \sum_m c_{mn} = \sum_n a_n^2 + b_n^2$ and $\sum_m \sum_n c_{mn} = \sum_n a_n^2 + \sum_n b_n^2$, both of which are the same by Tonelli.

Comment: @TaylorTed: If a sequence $(c_n)_n$ is non-negative (e.g. $c_n = a_n^2+b_n^2$) then the sum of partial sums $(S_m)_m$, i.e. $S_m = \sum_{n=0}^m c_n$, is monotonically increasing. From the monotone convergence theorem it follows that $(S_m)_m$ converges if and only if it is bounded from above.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint :** Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.$$\sum a_nb_n\le \left(\sum a_n^2\right)^{1/2}.\left(\sum b_n^2\right)^{1/2}$$

Comment: Can you give some counter examples

Comment: What example ??

Comment: I want to do this question without doing proof if possible. Also can you please tell me use of Cauchy Schwartz inequality

Comment: I already mention the inequality in my answer...

Comment: @S.P he means "why is the inequality that you did write useful?"

Comment: Also, you may want to put absolute values in the LHS.

Comment: @ClementC. The inequality is still true since $x\leq |x|$ but yes, I guess if you are very strict the above is not CS.

Comment: What I meant is: you need the absolute values to show the absolute convergence of the series.

Comment: I don not get the answer

Comment: How does product less than infinity justifies convergence

Comment: @ Taylor Ted) First you need to read the definition of convergence of series from your text book..